# MATLAB overlaying white area of binary image with rgb image

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation, imagefilter

I am using MATLAB 2012b.

I was able to get the objects outline in an image:
[image]
using method of Active Contour Segmentation and the result is in binary mask:

[image]

How can I fill the white area of the binary image with the original rgb image?

Basically what I want is to make the background completely black.

Here is my code:

```
gambarOri = imread(pathGambar);
A = rgb2gray(gambarOri ); 
mask = zeros(size(A)); mask(10:end-10,10:end-10) = 1; 
BW = activecontour(A, mask, 500);
figure, subplot(1, 2, 1), imshow(A), title('Grayscale'); 
subplot(1, 2, 2), imshow(BW), title('Segmented image in Binary');
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannon overlay an RGB on a binary image, since the data types do not match. What you can do is to modify your RGB image according to the binary image. For instance you can replace values of the RGB image in `false` areas of `BW` with zeros:

```
% separating RGB channels:
R = gambarOri(:, :, 1);
G = gambarOri(:, :, 2);
B = gambarOri(:, :, 3);
% placing zeros where BW is FALSE:
R(~BW) = 0;
G(~BW) = 0;
B(~BW) = 0;
% concatenate color layers into final result:
blackBG = cat(3, R, G, B);
% figure; imshow(blackBG)
```

With this result for your provided image:
[image]

Comment: So it is impossible to overlay images of different data types, thank you for the fact. By the way I tried your method and the [result](http://i.imgur.com/Gh4JJqc.jpg) does not concatenate the layers into black background. Does that mean my BW false area is not the white region?

Comment: Well, that looks weird, because if you copy and paste my code after yours, you should get same result as what I got. did you miss something in this process? Or maybe you did other operations on the variables in the mean time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun):

```
blackBG = uint8(bsxfun(@times, double(gambarOri), BW));
```